# KendoUi - Textbox in a toolbar

Tags: kendo-ui, textbox, toolbar

I am new to KendoUI (been using ExtJS for years) and was trying to build a toolbar which will need a textbox and I could not find any reference to how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out and am posting it here for others.

Simply add this to your items collection:

```
{ template: "<input type='text' id='address' class='k-textbox'>" },
```

If you want to add a label do this:

```
{ template: "<label>Address:</label>" },
{ template: "<input type='text' id='address' class='k-textbox'>" },
```

The k-textbox class skins your textbox properly.

It looks like you can put pretty much anything in the template items type.

If others have better ways or more info please share.